# Binary Serialization Backend for Orange

Tags: module, d, binary-serialization

Why doesn't the library [`Orange`](https://github.com/jacob-carlborg/orange) support a binary serialization backend in addition to its XML? Is it because D currently cannot access/reflect on its binary representation or is it just not prioritized yet? If possible what D language features and/or `Phobos` modules should I use to realize a binary serialization backend for `Orange`?

For D2 I guess it should be straightforward considering we have [`std.binmanip`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_bitmanip.html) right?

Comment: See this [feature request](https://github.com/jacob-carlborg/orange/issues/12) for some discussion. tl;dr the developer isn't familiar with binary serialization, and has reservations about compatibility.

Comment: I am sure developer will accept sane pull-requests... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [msgpack-d](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-d) library which provides binary serialization in MessagePack format. From http://msgpack.org/:

> MessagePack is an efficient binary serialization format. It lets you exchange data among multiple languages like JSON but it's faster and smaller. For example, small integers (like flags or error code) are encoded into a single byte, and typical short strings only require an extra byte in addition to the strings themselves.